# Getting error while hashing password with bcrypt: can not find module bcrypt_lib.node

Tags: node.js, npm, bcrypt

I'm working on an api project with node.js and receive this error while trying to hash my code with bcrypt package :

```
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/emad/work/node.js/npm-demo/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node'
Require stack:
- /home/emad/work/node.js/npm-demo/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js
- /home/emad/work/node.js/npm-demo/routes/users.js
- /home/emad/work/node.js/npm-demo/index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/emad/work/node.js/npm-demo/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:6:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/emad/work/node.js/npm-demo/routes/users.js:1:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/emad/work/node.js/npm-demo/index.js:8:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/emad/work/node.js/npm-demo/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js',
    '/home/emad/work/node.js/npm-demo/routes/users.js',
    '/home/emad/work/node.js/npm-demo/index.js'
  ]
}
```

My OS is a Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS and I installed all the dependecies that was written down in bcrypt page in npm site

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try below steps and run:-

1. Delete node_modules folder
2. run `npm cache clean --force`
3. npm install

Comment: FWIW, this fixed it for me. Running on a node docker container

Comment: Thanks for the solution. In my case it happened with zero messages, I had to debug the `imports` and then see it was failing at bcrypt... then I changed from `import` to `require` so I could see the error and found your suggestion. That's really bad.